# Passing float to function in BASH

Tags: bash, type-conversion, sh

Hi I'm trying to make a simple shell script, making it possible to run some python codes without me having to restart every simulation. The problem rises when I try to pass some arguments to the python program. The idea is written below

```
for i in 1.0 0.1 0.01
do
  python3 Code.py --arg=i
done
```

Is there a possibility to run such arguments? At this point I get errors like `invalid argument for 'i': could not convert string to float: 'i'`, since bash only handles integers, not floats.

Comment: Because Code.py is part of a bigger code, which I know nothing about. Because of this it will already throw an error before evaluating the first line of code. Since my work is part of a huge project, I do not want to change this.

Comment: Since you're saying this is your first time writing a shell script: https://www.shellcheck.net/ is a shell linter that is very useful. In this case, it would have pointed out that `i` appears to be unused.

Comment: Also, the error message is from Python, not Bash.

Comment: @BenjaminW., I know but since it is generated by passing a wrong command in the .sh file, I wanted to know how to approach the problem in the .sh file

Comment: Sure - just pointing out that it has nothing to do with Bash only handling integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently passing in the letter `i`, which is indeed not a valid float nor integer.

Instead, pass in the number stored in the variable `i`, such as `1.0`, by expanding the variable: `--arg="$i"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this worked perfectly. This is my first making a .sh file, so my appologies if the question was stupid. Will accept the answer when the time treshold has passed.